# Bloomberg desktop API Unspicified field value

Tags: c#, .net, bloomberg

Im currently working on a C # application to extract data from Bloomberg via API V3 .NET.

Unfortunately I can not find the solution when the field of an ISIN is not entered in Bloomberg.

Let me explain, I have two isin and I have to recover an information field for each of these two isin.

the field is as follows: MAX_REDEMP_FEE

This field has a value for the first ISIN but not the second because the value is not set in Bloomberg for the second ISIN.

[image]

If I use the Excel extension of Bloomberg and I want to retrieve the same information for these ISINs I have the following result

[image]

That's what I would do using C #, ie, if information is missing automatically put the value "NA", I use the code below and if a field in extraction is missing, my program stops because it can not find the value.

```
                switch (msg.MessageType.ToString())
                {
                    case "ReferenceDataResponse":

                        Element securityDataArray = msg.GetElement("securityData");

                        for (int index = 0; index < securityDataArray.NumValues; index++)
                        {
                            Element securityData = securityDataArray.GetValueAsElement(index);
                            Element fieldData = securityData.GetElement("fieldData");

                            double maxRedempFee = fieldData.GetElementAsFloat64("MAX_REDEMP_FEE");

                            Console.WriteLine(maxRedempFee);
                        }
```

How can i put a default value to maxRedempFee if missing?

Regards.

Comment: `if (securityDataArray.NumValues == 0) /* fee not available */` ?

Answer (score 0):

On a ReferenceDataRequest the field is not returned if it has no value.
In this case you could use the .HasElement("MAX_REDEMP_FEE", true); to determine whether the field is even present in the response.  If it returns false then you can assign the NA/NA value of your choice; if it returns true then you use your .GetElementAs... method as usual.